# The Ajax pagination to my account not run

Tags: ajax, laravel, pagination

I would like to create an Ajax pagination of my articles in my account, here is my code that I created but it does not work I do not know how to do.
MyaccountController

```
  public function viewProfile($username) {

    if($username) {

        $user = User::where('username', $username)->firstOrFail();
    } else {
        $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
    }

    return view('site.user.account', [

        'user' => $user,
        'articles' => $user->articles()->orderByDesc('created_at')->paginate(4),


    ]);


}
```

I would like to have `the javascript code`

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

     $(document).on('click','.pagination a',function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         e.stopPropagation();
         e.stopImmediatePropagation();
         var url = $(this).attr('href');
         $.ajax({
             url: url,
             method: 'GET',
             data: {},
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function (result) {
                 if (result.status == 'ok'){
                     $('#userListingGrid').html(result.listing);
                 }else{
                     alert("Error when get pagination");
                 }
             }
         });
         return false;
     })

 });
```

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

I would have a check on your controller for an ajax request like so:

```
public function viewProfile($username) {

  if($username) {
    $user = User::where('username', $username)->firstOrFail();
  } else {
    $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
  }

  if(request()->ajax()){
    return response()->json(['user' => $user, 'articles' => $user->articles()->orderByDesc('created_at')->paginate(4);
  }

  return view('site.user.account', [

    'user' => $user,
    'articles' => $user->articles()->orderByDesc('created_at')->paginate(4),
  ]);
}
```

Then you don't have to load your view every time and you can let your javascript functions take care of the DOM manipulating of the results. Not sure if that's what you are looking for. I know that you would probably need a `{{$articles->links()}}` at the end of your view to go through each page.